# Counting items within a list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I can't figure out how to count within a list of lists that was imported from a txt file. It is just a list of job details (about 100 jobs).

Each list format looks like this:

```
['Business Analyst', 'Hotwire.com', 'San Francisco CA', 'NA', 'Full Time', 'Bachelors', '3', 'Business Analysis', 'Business Intelligence', 'IT development', 'UML', 'BPMN', 'Applied Analytics', 'Statistics', 'Communication Skills', 'Sales Experience', 'Organized', 'Detail-Oriented']
```

I want to make a new list of a specific detail to count and graph eventually.

For example, I want to create a list of cities (index[2]).

```
data = []
with open('Travel Industry Jobs.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(line.strip().split(','))

f.close()

for i in data:
    count = 0
    city = data[i].count("San Francisco CA")
    count += city
```

Comment: Do you have any code that you've started with for our review?

Comment: Extract column by index. If you want to unique city names, then put them into set.

Comment: do u have lists of lists? If yes then then try to flatten it and count them over

Comment: Edit it into the question; don't cram it into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull out a column easily with list comprehensions

```
cities = [row[2] for row in data]
```

You could also use other tools such as `collections.Counter` with a generator that emits all of the cities. Here each city gets its own key in a dictionary. Any minor spelling deviations get different entries, so beware

```
citycount = collections.Counter(row[2] for row in data)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
for t in a:
  print len(t)
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the question.